# Setting up Rascal on VSCode

Tags: rascal

I have been having trouble installing the Rascal plugin on VSCode, but I can't seem to get the rascal terminal to work or even being able to setup a working Rascal project on VSCode. Please I need a step by step process of properly installing Rascal on VSCode

I tried installing the Rascal extension on VSCode but it doesn't work instead it suggested I download the Rascal VSIX file, but after downloading the file and adding it as an extension on VSCode I still couldn't get the Rascal terminal or generate a working Rascal project.

Comment: Normally you should get some error message? Could you share that? Installation should only be done via de extensions tab of vscode, never install custom VSIX files. Otherwise, please open an github issue, as you might have hit a bug:  https://github.com/usethesource/rascal-language-servers/issues

Comment: Thanks for the response, removed the custom install restarted my VSCode and reinstalled rascal now it works fine

Comment: Good day @DavyLandman; I have some questions on setting up Rascal on VSCode. How create a new Rascal project on VSCode? How do I register a new Rascal language parser on VSCode? Also links to a Rascal projects developed in VSCode would be appreciated.

Comment: Pius; the docs on VScode are still being written as we speak. For now the best thing is to look at the example code here: https://github.com/usethesource/rascal-language-servers/blob/main/rascal-lsp/src/main/rascal/demo/lang/pico/LanguageServer.rsc This contains everything you need to register a language parser in VScode. You can register more contributions if you want, but the parser is the only necessary component at first.